# Error in then of updatingProfile firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I am trying to do an api call using redux in `then` of the updateProfile using firebase but I am getting this error:
 `TypeError: Cannot read property 'fetchProfile' of undefined`

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {

let user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
  user.updateProfile({
    displayName: `${form.firstName} ${form.lastName}`,
    email: form.email,
    phoneNumber: `${form.countryCode}${form.phone}`,
  }).then(function() {
    this.props.fetchProfile();
    Navigation.pop(componentId);
  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("error edit profile: ",error,error.response);
    this._registerFMSG.showMessage({
      message: '',
      description: error,
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: `this` may not be referring to the object you think inside that promise.

Comment: Use arrow functions, not regular functions. Regular functions have their own `this` definition, arrow functions use their context's one.

Comment: that's inside `componentDidUpdate` how would I use arrow function in this?

Comment: @RowanX `.then(() => { this.props.fetchProfile()....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is explicitly stating that `this.props` is undefined.

In javascript, care needs to be taken with respect to the use of the `this` keyword, since it has different contextual meaning depending on how it's used.

It is likely that in this case, `this` is referencing an object that you are not intending, because you are passing in a callback function that is called by another object.

Your callback:

```
function() {
    this.props.fetchProfile();
    Navigation.pop(componentId);
  }
```

The MDN on `this` is a good reference:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

This should work for you:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
var currentProps = this.props
let user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
  user.updateProfile({
    displayName: `${form.firstName} ${form.lastName}`,
    email: form.email,
    phoneNumber: `${form.countryCode}${form.phone}`,
  }).then(function() {
    currentProps.fetchProfile();
    Navigation.pop(componentId);
  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("error edit profile: ",error,error.response);
    _registerFMSG.showMessage({
      message: '',
      description: error,
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: can you explain to me why `this` is specifically undefined inside `.then` ? it works everywhere else inside `componentDidUpdate`